# CSS HTML with ASP.NET Core, table header text folding differently on localhost and production(Docker)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

So there is a problem with how a header renders on localhost and on production server. The CSS is the same as well as HTML, and both run on linux, or well MacOS VisalStudio and Docker ubuntu. On the localhost the Task Name and subsequent columns are in one line while on the server they are all split at whitespace. Any ideas why?, this is in Chrome, but no matter what browser I user the result is the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this means some CSS style is missing after your web is deployed. This involves table style or the one called `white-space` or `word-break`, `word-wrap`. You can inspect the item (e.g: at `Task Name`) on the 2 views and try to detect the differences in the `Computed Style` section (each browser should provide a tab like that to show all computed styles of an element in the inspecting/inspector mode). There must be surely a difference here. This has nothing to do with `asp.net core`.

Comment: @KingKing there is only one difference, the width, one is 141px the other is 66px, but it is greyed out, i have no idea, what could be the culprit. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not so sure, you may still miss something. The nature of this issue is just simple, definitely there is some difference in CSS style (from CSS files or applied via javascript). However to pinpoint it in this specific case requires some effort. I'm really blinded here and would give no more guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `white-space: nowrap;` to the  of the header.